# misclassification on SGDclassifier using loss='hinge' for SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I have a huge dataset around 5-8 million data and 70-80 classes, till now in future data and classes will increase.

I used hashingvectorizer() for feature selection because I am building incremental learning model(I am not using CountVectorizer(),Tfidf() because i have heard they don't support for Incremental learning)

so I have multiclass classification problem and I have used SDClassifier with SVM using partial_fit method. but while in testing it is producing misclassification.

1) Is it because of I am doing something wrong in feature selection

2) Is Unbalanced data the problem?

3) Parameter tuning?

4) How to decide no of iteration? Any method? (data is increasing)

5) Any other feedbacks are welcome.

please provide some example with your answer it will be helpful

Comment: 2) is one factor.  3)What max_iter value u set ? If we can provide more training data for each label, misclassification can be avoided to some extent. Why using only SGD ? Is the model accuracy still bad with other [incremental learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) supported algorithms ? What kind of data you have (image/text/numbers/audio...)?

Comment: @user1  i am using max_iter= 1000 and data imbalanced is huge problem i am dealing with. data is in text format